# Scanning Assemblies with DryIoc

Tags: mef, dryioc

I'm trying to use the DryIoc Mef library to scan all assemblies with the Export Attribute

I see this link about [Mef](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/Extensions/MefAttributedModel.md#assembly-scan) with DryIoc

I changed the method to RegisterExports, but the IGreeter property is not being injected. If I register each one by itself it works (Foo/Greeter).

```
using DryIoc;
using DryIoc.MefAttributedModel;
using System;
using DryIocAttributes;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
    public static IContainer C;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Program.C = new Container().With(rules => rules.With( propertiesAndFields: PropertiesAndFields.Auto)).WithMefAttributedModel();

        Program.C.RegisterExports(new Assembly[] { typeof(Foo).GetAssembly() });
        
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Message();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IGreeter
{
    string ShowGreet();
}

[ExportEx]
public class Greeter : IGreeter
{
    public Greeter() { }
    public string ShowGreet()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

[ExportEx]
public class Foo
{
    public IGreeter greet { get; set; }

    public void Message()
    {
        Program.C.InjectPropertiesAndFields(this);
        Console.WriteLine($"Show {greet.ShowGreet()}");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you possibly look at this @dadhi

Comment: works with Program.C.Register<IGreeter, Greeter>();

Answer (score 0):

Interface IGreeter needed attribute

```
[InheritedExport]    
public interface IGreeter
{
    string ShowGreet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the change to the `ExportEx(typeof(IGreeter))` or to `ExportMany`. The latter will discover the implemented interfaces and will export those. Also pay attention to the types visibility - `ExportMany` does not export non-public types by default, but it can be changed with attribute properties.